# Por que me da error? Es en zinjai

Tags: c

> Crear un programa en C que contenga una estructura llamada “Alumno”, que tenga como campos el nombre del alumno, el sexo (f o m), y la edad. El programa debe permitir introducir una cantidad finita de alumnos. Contar la cantidad de mujeres y varones que hay en el grupo, y la edad mayor de los alumnos. Luego visualice la cantidad de mujeres y varones, así como la información del alumno cuya edad es mayor. Use punteros a estructura.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Alumno{
    char nombre[20][100];
    char sexo;
    int edad;
};

int main(){
    int i,j=0,N,may,k=0,m=0,f=0;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    struct Alumno z[N],*dat=NULL;
    do{
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno %d:",i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(z[i].nombre[i],100,stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(z[i].nombre[i],100,stdin);
        z[i].nombre[i][strlen(z[i].nombre[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Ingrese el sexo de %s(m o f):",z[i].nombre[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&z[i].sexo);
        printf("Ingrese la edad de %s:",z[i].nombre[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&z[i].edad);
        i++;
        j++;
    }while(i<N);
    dat=z;
    may=0;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        if(dat[i].edad>may){
            k=i;
            may=dat[i].edad;
        }
        if(dat[i].sexo=='m'){
            m++;
        }
        if(dat[i].sexo=='f'){
            f++;
        }
    }
    printf("Total de mujeres: %d\n",f);
    printf("Todal de varones: %d\n",m);
    printf("El alumno con mayor edad es:\n");
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",dat[k].nombre[k]);
    printf("Edad: %d\n",dat[k].edad);
    printf("Sexo: %c",dat[k].sexo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Qué es `zinjai` ? ¿ Que relevancia tiene respecto a la pregunta ?

Comment: Dices que te da error, pero no comentas qué error te sale. No somos adivinos, por lo que podrías reportarnos qué tipo de error te da, qué has intentado hacer para solucionarlo, etc. A primera vista veo que la variable `i` no la inicializas, cuando según tu lógica la debes inicializar a '0' para que el primer alumno sea el '1'. Luego veo que pides ingresar el nombre del alumno 2 veces. También veo que utilizas una variable `j` a modo de contador para el bucle `for`, pero ya tienes guardada en tu variable `N` el número de alumnos ingresados, por lo que no te haría falta... Reporta el error, pls

Comment: ¿Para qué utilizas una matriz bidimensional, `char nombre[20][100];` para almacenar el nombre?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes múltiples errores en el código. No necesitas una matriz bidimensional para almacenar el nombre, y la forma en que lees el nombre y lo almacenas no es correcta.

Cuando llamas a `scanf` así `scanf(z[i].nombre[i],100,stdin);` le estás diciendo que la cadena de formato está en el buffer `z[i].nombre[i]`, lo cual es claramente incorrecto, le estás especificando el valor `100` como si fuera la dirección del buffer destino y `stdin` como otra dirección de otro buffer destino. El error *segmentation fault* que sale en el programa es debido a que `scanf` intenta escribir en la dirección absoluta `100` el texto que se ha entrado antes en el buffer `z[i].nombre[i]`.

Otro error, no menor, es cuando pones `z[i].nombre[i][strlen(z[i].nombre[i]) - 1] = '\0';`, con esto estás eliminando el último carácter del nombre. `scanf` se encarga de poner el terminador de cadena `\0` cuando lee una cadena de caracteres.

Te dejo aquí un código corregido que hace lo que te han pedido y que utiliza punteros para recorrer la lista de alumnos.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Alumno{
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo;
    int edad;
};

int main(){
    int N;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    
    // Inicializar el contador de alumnos: i
    int i = 0;
    
    // Inicializar el puntero para recorrer la lista
    struct Alumno alumnos[N];
    struct Alumno *alumno = &alumnos[0];
    
    do {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s", alumno->nombre);
        //alumnos[i].nombre[strlen(alumnos[i].nombre) - 1] = '\0';
        
        printf("Ingrese el sexo de %s (m o f): ",alumno->nombre);
        // Se pone el espacio antes de %c para descartar el \n del dato anterior.
        scanf(" %c",&alumno->sexo);
        // aquí falta validar que se ha introducido correctamente el sexo
        
        printf("Ingrese la edad de %s: ",alumno->nombre);
        scanf("%d",&alumno->edad);
        
        i++;
        alumno++;
    } while (i < N);
    
    // Inicializar los datos del de mayor edad con valores inválidos.
    int mayor_edad = -1;
    int idx_mayor_edad = -1;
    
    // Inicializar los valores a calcular.
    int cant_m=0, cant_f=0;
    
    // Recorrer la lista desde el inicio.
    alumno = &alumnos[0];
    
    for(i=0; i<N; i++,alumno++){
        if(alumno->edad > mayor_edad){
            mayor_edad=alumno->edad;
            idx_mayor_edad = i;
        }
        
        if(alumno->sexo=='m'){
            cant_m++;
        }
        else if(alumno->sexo=='f'){
            cant_f++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total de mujeres: %d\n",cant_f);
    printf("Todal de varones: %d\n",cant_m);
    printf("El alumno con mayor edad es:\n");
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",alumnos[idx_mayor_edad].nombre);
    printf("Edad: %d\n",alumnos[idx_mayor_edad].edad);
    printf("Sexo: %c",alumnos[idx_mayor_edad].sexo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

En el código no hay chequeo de errores ni de validez de los datos. Creo que un buen ejercicio sería que intentaras incorporarlos.